# How to remove the last string token from a path

Tags: c

I have a string like `"\\\\PC1\\Users\\Administrator\\Last\\"`. I wanted to remove the last part of the string, I mean Last. I used the following code but it doesn't work.

```
 char str1[] = "\\\\PC1\\C$\\Users\\Administrator\\Last\\";

 char* temp;
 temp = strchr(str1, '\\');   //Get the pointer to char token
 *temp = '\0';
 printf("%s\n", str1);
```

Comment: How does it "not work"? What does `strchr` do? How is `Administrator` the last part when you have `Last` too? there?

Comment: You should look at the `strrchr` function. Note the extra `r`.

Comment: What output are you getting, and what you do expect to get?

Comment: For C++ (C++17 and later), you should be able to use [`parent_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path) of a path object.  Alas, now this question is no longer tagged with `c++`.

Comment: Before an answer can be provided, some additional information is required. What should the output be if the string is `char str[] = "\\\\Admin\\Last"`? How about `char str[] = "\\\\"` or `char str[] = "\\"`?

Comment: @user3386109 The output I needed from the above string is just "\\\\PC1\\Users\\Administrator\\" but I couldn't find a valid way to find a method to remove the last directory name from the path.

Comment: @KLightning: what was wrong with scanning backwards over the string until you find a backslash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better served using `strrchr()` to obtain a pointer to the last occurrence of `'\\'` in `str1` rather than obtaining a pointer to the first with `strchr()`. All that is needed is to loop while getting a pointer to the last `'\\'` and check if the next character is the *nul-terminating* character, overwriting `'\\'` each time with the *nul-terminating* character. On exit, check you exited as a result of finding `'\\'` where the following character was not the *nul-character* and *nul-terminate* once more for your final solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char str1[] = "\\\\PC1\\C$\\Users\\Administrator\\Last\\";
    char *temp = strrchr (str1, '\\');      /* find last \\ */

    while (temp && !temp[1]) {              /* valid ptr & next is nul-character */
        *temp = 0;                          /* nul-terminate at current */
        temp = strrchr (str1, '\\');        /* get next last \\ */
    }
    if (temp)                               /* if not NULL */
        *temp = 0;                          /* nul-terminate at current */

    printf ("%s\n", str1);                  /* output results */
}
```

If you want to preserve the last path separator following `"...Administrator\"`, then make the final termination at `temp[1]`, e.g.

```
    if (temp)                               /* if not NULL */
        temp[1] = 0;                        /* nul-terminate at next */
```

This will work regardless of whether the string ends with `'\\'`. For example, it will work equally well with:

```
char str1[] = "\\\\PC1\\C$\\Users\\Administrator\\Last";
```

**Example Use/Output**

Removing the path separator after `"...Administrator"` by making the final termination at `*temp`:

```
$ ./bin/trimlast
\\PC1\C$\Users\Administrator
```

or if preserving the final separator terminating at `temp[1]`:

```
$ ./bin/trimlast
\\PC1\C$\Users\Administrator\
```

(**note:** windows accepts `'/'` instead of `'\\'` in virtually all path circumstances in C -- which makes things a bit easier on the eyes)

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.